# how to combine Directions Service and multiple markers together

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a map similar to https://jsfiddle.net/maiiiii/onca4rge/4/.

Now I would like to replace my geocoder with the Directions function.

I am studying the code here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions

What I did was copy and paste everything except `initMap` function into my code --> https://jsfiddle.net/maiiiii/onca4rge/4/.

I put the following to my initial map:

```
new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
```

However, I do not see the service function. When I have them separate, they both work fine.

I would like to have Directions Service to work separate from the filter.

My result does not show the Directions Service, I only see may map with points. Since I would like both of them to work separately, I do not see why they don't both show on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Places library in your Google Maps API script. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maiiiii/onca4rge/4/) runs perfectly as is after you add this library, including both the Place Autocomplete service and the Directions service.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi @evan. I wonder if you are able to help me with the situation below. I am trying to use the code found at https://thewebstorebyg.wordpress.com/tag/google-maps-like-directions-panel/, and get it to be combined with my markers. so I try replacing my currently direction services with the code. As a result, I am able to show the direction panel with map centered to the place I want, However, my markers are not showing. there is no error and I wonder what could I possibly do wrong.

Comment: Hey @Maggster! Sure i'm happy to take a look, did you create a question for this issue yet?

Comment: hi evan. thank you for the support. I can trying to simplify the work by adding buttons to the web page instead of combining two sources into one as I realized the languages used and how they formatted are very different. so I have my question posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742958/how-to-add-button-and-trigger-function-using-google-map-api?noredirect=1#comment101929661_57742958.